# How to make a see through silk material?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I have tried a couple of things now but can't seem to get the material just right. I am trying to create a white blouse material that looks like the picture below. Has anybody got some tips or maybe some samples that are close to it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how physically correct this is but artistically it should look fine.

> Note: I've exaggerated this effect a bit to be better visible.

[image: final]

Mix **Principled BSDF** with **Translucent** (pure white color) shader trough **Layer Weight > Fresnel**. You can tweak **Fresnel** to make it more/less transparent.

[image: nodes]

Comment: Look way better than all my attempts thanks ;)

Comment: Your node work is worth stealing for my scrapbook. 