# How to make thin silk material which can be seen through? (I tried both questions on stack exchange relate to 'silk')

Tags: materials

I'm trying to make silk material that can be looked through like [this](https://www.artstation.com/artwork/xJQ9kR) (made by Pablo Dobarro)
[image]

[image]

When I tried to make silk material, there are two answers for this, but both materials were not translucent enough.

[image]
[how to produce a Silk/Satin material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/113961/how-to-produce-a-silk-satin-material)
I followed this answer, and the result is like this.

[image]

[How to make a see through silk material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140422/how-to-make-a-see-through-silk-material)
I followed this answer, and the result is like this.

I really want to make this smooth and translucent silk material.

Could you give me advice how to make this material?

Comment: Looks like you are using Eevee, what is your render settings? Is Blend mode in material set to Alpha Blend/Hashed/Clip?

Comment: or just provide your blend file so we can check it out...

Comment: First of all I think the silk material should not (only) have a translucent material, if you want to make it slightly transparent. Maybe look up the difference between translucency and transparency. A translucent material lets light pass through, so every object between the light source and the translucent material will only show as a shadow. In your example you can clearly see the skin color of the thighs show through, which is caused by transparency, not translucency. But nevertheless silk is translucent, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use this node setup:

[image]

Here you see the different looks depending on your Fac value in your mix shader:

[image]

For eevee you need to choose alpha blend or alpha hashed mode for your blend mode in your material.

[image]

Here the comparison with fresnel node, thank to Robin and Gordon:

[image]

[image]

with HDRI

[image]

Comment: Maybe use a _Fresnel_ node for the _Mix_ factor instead of a constant value, because the silk will be less transparent when viewed from a shallow angle. Or even better, use the fresnel (maybe in combination with a _Color Ramp_) for the _Transmission_ value of the _Principled BSDF_ and no _Transparent BSDF_. At least that's how I would do it in _Cycles_ (I never use _Eevee_, sorry).

Comment: + @Gordon  maybe  _Sheen_? This could be the place for it.. but that's just a tweak.

Comment: @RobinBetts _Sheen_ is good for silk as a surface quality, but doesn't give any transparency. Or I misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: @Gordon Guess you're right.. just thinking of it as an and/or for Fresnel, for reflection/opacity at raking angles.

Comment: thank you guys, i updated my answer

Comment: Hm, I just use Fresnel with a value of 1.45 and adjust it a little with the _Color Ramp_... but okay, if it works. And you're right taking transparency, my suggestion to use transmission is nonsense.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: are my eyes so bad or why am i not seeing that much difference between using Fresnel or not? or have i to move the camera to see that? or have i to use cycles?

Comment: @Chris The _Fresnel_ works the same in _Cycles_ and _Eevee_. You can't see a difference because your _Fresnel_ values are way too high. They should be between 1 and 2, and then you have to switch black and white to get the edges more opaque and the center more transparent.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation

Comment: @Chris I've made a comparison between different mix methods, here's an example image: [Different mixing methods](https://pasteall.org/pic/4ae6451f25b940df918808d7326530d0)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: Nice! Thank you!

Comment: I connect Fresnel, Principled BSDF, and Transparent BSDF to the mix shader. Then, changing blend mod to Alpha blend make perfect thin silk material, Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome